# Como puedo pasar una variable de PHP redireccionando sin incluirla en la URL

Tags: php

me gustaría pasar una variable con una redirección en php.

Si por ejemplo mi página es https://pagina.com/verificar=345 y genere una variable por ejemplo $verificar="si"; y redirija a https://pagina.com/contenido-verificado pero no quiero escribir la variable en la url

Me gustaría pasar la variable para que cuando alguien entre manualmente a https://pagina.com/contenido-verificado poder bloquear un contenido específico y que no se muestre si no has entrado desde el primer enlace.

Agradecería que alguien me pudiera ayudar, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar las sesiones de php.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['verificar'] = "si";
```

De esa manera en el archivo que lo necesites podrás acceder a ese valor realizando lo mismo.
Por ejemplo

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['verificar'];
```

Una vez no vayas a necesitar ese dato puedes usar unset

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['verificar']);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado